# Make button fill out a part of a contact form

Tags: javascript, html

I put a button beneath an SEO service I offer and when they click it I want it to direct them down to the contact form below and fill out the "service needed" area as "SEO". Is this possible?

```html
<!-- MY FORM THAT I WANT FILLED OUT AFTER THEY CLICK A BUTTON -->

<form id="contact-form" class="form" action="contact.php" method="POST" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="name"></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" tabindex="1" required>
              </div>                            
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="email"></label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" data-constraints="@NotEmpty @Email" placeholder="Your Email" tabindex="2" required>
              </div>                            
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="subject"></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Service Needed" tabindex="3">
              </div>                            
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="comments"></label>
                  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="comments" class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="Message..." tabindex="4" required></textarea>                                 
              </div>
              <div class="text-center">
                  <button type="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-start-order">Send Message</button>
              </div>
          </form>



<!-- BUTTON I USE -->
<a href="index.html#contact" class="btn btn-default">get a quote</a>
```

Comment: deleted them sorry

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  This is the contact form that you want to direct people to.  But where is the rest of the code so we can see what you're doing already to try and direct them?

Comment: Is this contact form embedded into the page, or is it on a different page? Are you using a server side language like php? I agree with @trav, we need to see more.

Comment: PHP is being used to direct the mail. The contact form is embedded into the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ready(function(){
    $('#myButtonID').click(function(){
         $('#subject').val('SEO');
         event.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor tag action otherwise animation wont work
         $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#contact-form').offset().top}, 300 /*duration*/);
         return false;
    });

});
```